# Getting location through network provider dose not work

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to get the current location through the network only, i don want to use gps location. So I have used following code.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private Button btn_view_form;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    private LatLng mLatLang;
    LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;
    private final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION = 10;

    private Intent mIntent;

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)


    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpUI();   

    }

    public void setUpUI()
    {

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION);

        } else {
            initializeLocationManager();
            requestLocation();
        }    

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! do the
                    // calendar task you need to do.

                    initializeLocationManager();
                    requestLocation();


                } else {
                    //   ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.locationAlert));
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.

                }
                return;
            }
            // other 'switch' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(MainActivity.this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(MainActivity.this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        // Log.e(Application.TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }

        try {
            gps_enabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        try {
            network_enabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            // notify user
            if(!isGPSEnabled(MainActivity.this))
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }

    }

    public class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {

        public LocationListener() {
        }

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);

            //get current location

            if(mLastLocation != null && !mLastLocation.equals("")) {
                mLastLocation.set(location);
                mLatLang = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,mLastLocation.getLatitude()+ "," +mLastLocation.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    //request for location, first by network, then by gps

    public void requestLocation() {

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static boolean isGPSEnabled (Context context){
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

}
```

By this code when my gps is off it dose not fetch the location details through the network though the network is ON. It shows both boolean variables of network_enabled and gps_enabled as false though the network is ON so network_enabled should be true.

I have added both the permissions of coarse location and fine location in the manifest.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

On the other side when I turn on the gps I get the location. Just not working trough the network.

Is there a problem in NETWORK_PROVIDER? What can be the problem?

Please help. Thank you..

Comment: On which device you are testing it ?

Comment: motorolo G4 plus its o.s is 7.0 @Heisen-Berg

Comment: I dont know about motorola, but some providers doesn't allow to get location through the network. I am saying this because I recently worked over a location based application, and when I tested it on `OnePlus` device, it not giving location through network. So, I am pretty sure about OnePlus. Tried to test this application on different device like xioami or samsung if it is showing location through network then motorola are also in OnePlus category.

Comment: The concern is we need to have location on for getting the location through network also right? I need to know can we track location without prompting the user about turning the location on if it is off. Is it possible?

Comment: Nope, it is almost impossible to get location without user concern. You have to as user if he or she want to share location or not. And also location permission is in dangerous permission category, so it is impossible.